# Stop Chef Overwriting XML added after chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef recipe for Wildfly that controls Wildflys domain.xml. But when we deploy WARs to Wildfly it adds and populates a deployment section to domain.xml. Chef will of course delete this section when it runs again as it does not match the template.

The recipe comes with an option to create a lock file to prevent any changes, but I want Chef to be able to run and update any proper changes without deleting the deployments section of domain.xml.

I could add the deployments to the template but the sha1 values change with each new deployment, id rather Chef figures out what is in the existing file and just keeps that. Deployment section looks like this:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="healthcheck.war" runtime-name="healthcheck.war">
        <content sha1="2a833c924625234ad160cb24c6f4b74007ad0815"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="jolokia.war" runtime-name="jolokia.war">
        <content sha1="c1261964977a401aa45c180037c2965983b7e22a"/>
    </deployment>
    ...
</deployments>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `domain.xml` created in a cookbook of yours or in an upstream one? There is a `action :create_if_missing` option, which sounds reasonable here.

Answer (score 0):

Guard the resource call with

```
template <your template> do
  ...
  not_if File.exist?(<path to .xml file>).to_s
end
```

That way if a file exists on that path it won't even evaluate if they are different, it will just skip the template block.

EDIT: not_if guards require a string instead of a Boolean, code fixed to reflect this.